# Issue using glTexCoordPointer()

Tags: c++, opengl, texturing

I'm fairly new to **OpenGL** (and GLSL) and I have an issue using `glTexCoordPointer()`.

I have the texture loaded in and it is rendering on the object correctly (a single quad) but I also get another quad appearing which is a single colour not a part of the loaded texture.

The arrays are defined as follows:

```
static const GLfloat obj_vert_buf[] = {
    -1, 0, -1,
    -1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 1,
    1, 0, -1
};

static const GLfloat obj_tex_buf[] = {
    0, 0, 
    0, 1, 
    1, 1,
    1, 0
};
```

And the relevant excerpt from the draw function:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT);

glGenBuffers(1, &obj_id);

glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, obj_tex_buf);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, obj_vert_buf);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, sizeof(obj_vert_buf) / sizeof(GLfloat));

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT);
```

To my understanding `glTexCoordPointer()`'s first argument specifies the number of elements per vertex which would be two as in:

```
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
```

The second argument is the type, `GLfloat`.

The third argument is the offset between each set of elements pertaining to each vertex, so zero after the two stated before (I have also tried it with `2 * sizeof(GLfloat)` to no change).

And the fourth argument is a pointer to the start of the data, i.e. `obj_tex_buf`.

The **quad renders correctly** and the texture is drawn on it correctly, but I get **another random shape** coming off from its centre and textured incorrectly, any thoughts would be great. The additional quad isn't visible without the `glTexCoordPointer()` line.

Comment: I think the third parameter of `glDrawArrays` should be 4 (the number of indices), but `sizeof(obj_vert_buf) / sizeof(GLfloat)` would be 12, so you are drawing extra garbage from memory.

Comment: Yes, you were right, thanks for the help.

Comment: What's this `glGenBuffers(1, &obj_id);` supposed to be doing in there? Btw, most of your code is totally deprecated OpenGL, since a _decade_ by now. If you're new to GL, better start with modern GL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml):

```
count
Specifies the number of indices to be rendered.
```

Thus you have to call `glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);`

Please note that `GL_QUADS` isn't officially supported anymore as of OpenGL 3.1.

Comment: You are very right, I thought the count was the number of array indices, not the number of vertex indices. That makes a lot of sense. Thank you